# How to get Account_id for twitter tweet scheduling?

Tags: android, twitter, scheduling, twitterkit

i was trying to schedule tweet through app i am developing.
Link i am following is :
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/creatives/api-reference/scheduled-tweets.html
where it specifies

Resource URL
https://ads-api.twitter.com/2/accounts/:account_id/scheduled_tweets
Can someone help me figure out what account_id is? and how to get it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That endpoint is part of Twitter's Ads API, and the account_id is the Twitter Ads account id (a 6 or 7 character string) you'd have received back from the API when the user authenticated.

Comment: thanks..i get it now.i have been checking wrong api.. scheduling post is only possible for ads account but not for regular accounts using api

Comment: @andy_piper, I'm also looking for my account_id. Is that something that I will recieve after Twitter approves my dev account? I was able to get the CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN & ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET right away.

Comment: You will definitely need an approved Developer account. In the Ads API, an `account_id` refers to the Ads account that a user account has access to. You can use the [Accounts endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/campaign-management/api-reference/accounts) to get that information for the authenticated user.